# Switch loop wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring

Have a house from 1960s I’m renovating. I installed new pot lights into my ceiling and brought the wire down to an existing switch only to realize it was a switch controlling the rooms outlet. It’s an end line switch with the white wire hot. Can I rewire the closest outlet (the one before this switch) and get power from that outlet to my switch and then light fixtures or will the neutral wire going into the outlet be hot as well?

Comment: are you keeping the outlet? I don't think you can have any outlets on a lighting branch.

Comment: Are you willing to sacrifice the ability to switch the outlet?

Comment: Yes I’d like to keep the outlet. I don’t want to be able to switch the outlets. Don’t need that ability anymore.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of both the switch and outlet boxes involved please?